# How to get the fonts of a QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

I have a `QTextEdit` that displays text with multiple fonts. I want to get each character (or text block) with its font information.
I've tried getting the `QTextBlock`'s for the `QTextDocument`. But it seems to be a string with ontype of font.

Is there a way to get the fonts of a `QTextEdit`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get this information from the `QTextDocument`:

```
QTextDocument doc;

QTextBlock currentBlock = doc.firstBlock();
while (currentBlock.isValid()) {
    QTextBlockFormat blockFormat = currentBlock.blockFormat();
    QTextCharFormat charFormat = currentBlock.charFormat();
    QFont font = charFormat.font();

    // each QTextBlock holds multiple fragments of text, so iterate over it:
    QTextBlock::iterator it;
    for (it = currentBlock.begin(); !(it.atEnd()); ++it) {
        QTextFragment currentFragment = it.fragment();
        if (currentFragment.isValid()) {
            // a text fragment also has a char format with font:
            QTextCharFormat fragmentCharFormat = currentFragment.charFormat();
            QFont fragmentFont = fragmentCharFormat.font();
            // etc...
        }
    }

    currentBlock = currentBlock.next();
}
```